# Random video list from Vimeo

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I am creating a Vimeo HTML5 app for digital TV box. When user open the app, he/she should be able to see a list of random videos from Vimeo without logging into the vimeo account.

How can I achieve this?

The second thing is that I want to call vimeo api without authentication  .

Is there anyway to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Random videos are not supported, but you could make it pseudo random. Dig through the endpoint documentation: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints. There are a lot of ways to get videos. Search, channels, albums, groups etc.

You can make unauthenticated requests by generating an unauthenticated access token once, and using it for all of your requests: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication#unauthenticated-requests

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Simple API [Channels part](https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/methods/vimeo.channels.getAll) here which is able to return a list of public channels based on the ordering you need. You can order channels by `newest` to get a frequently-refreshed new feed. Then you can retrieve infos about each channel using [this API](https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/methods/vimeo.channels.getInfo).

It's unfortunately impossible to retrieve videos from a channel without user authentication but you can display a list of channels instead.

Comment: The links you included are both to the Advanced API, and has been deprecated. It will be shut down at some point in the future, and no new API applications will work with it. Additionally it is possible to retrieve videos from a channel without user authentication.